# I can't display image pulling from database. it shows HTML codes instead of picture

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli

I upload picture on my database using:

new.php:

```
<form  action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/hen/insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image1">
```

insert.php:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"hen" );

$image1=addslashes($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
$image1=file_get_contents($image1);
$image1=base64_encode($image1);

$sq="INSERT INTO hen (image1) VALUES 
('$image1')
```

till this point everything is fine. I see image upload on DB successfully on database using     longblob type.

but when I want ti display image on another page using:

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,"hen" );
$id =$_REQUEST['id'];
$U=$_REQUEST['U'];
if ($U=="Supervisor"){
// sending query
$s=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `hen` WHERE `hen`.`HenNumber` = '$id'");   


echo "<table>";

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($s)){
     $data = base64_decode($row["image1"]);
     $im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($data));
     echo 'study ID: '.$row["0"];
     echo " <tr>";
      header("content-type :image/png");
    echo "<img border=\"0\" src=\"".$im."\" width=\"102\" alt=\"Your Name\" height=\"91\">";
    echo " </tr>";  


 }
 header("content-type :image/jpg");
 echo " </table>";
```

I only see html codes instead of my real picture.

Comment: It makes absolute no sense to try and send a Content-Type header at this point. A Content-Type header would be needed, if you were outputting binary image data for one single image in response to the request - but that is not at all what you are doing here.

Comment: (And of course images do rather not belong into the database in the first place.)

Comment: as you see I have header("content-type :image/png"); there.

Comment: Yes. And as I said, it makes absolutely no sense there. You can not mix different types of resources in one response. You either need a stand-alone script that outputs the data for one single image, and only that; or you would need to "inline" the binary image data, keyword Data URI, keyword bad-idea-in-this-context.

Comment: that helped. I used a separate script and that resolved the issue.  thank you.